# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scrollTo')

Tags: javascript, angular, scrollto

This below code giving me runtime error. I just want the browser to go to top while the page is routed from footer link. It just stick to the bottom and need to scroll.

`document.getElementsByClassName('homemenu').scrollTo(0, 0);`

`header.component.html`

```
<header class="top-head homemenu" *ngIf="showMenu == 'home'">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" [ngClass]="{'justify-content-center': onlyLogo}">
            <div class="col-3 lm-logo"><a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="showSiteMap = !showSiteMap"><img src="/assets/images/lm-logo.svg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-9" *ngIf="!onlyLogo">
              <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
                <ul class="menu_wrap d-flex">
                  <ng-container *ngIf="homemenu; else individual_page">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/']" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/individual']" routerLinkActive="active">Individuals</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/corporate']" routerLinkActive="active">Corporate</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/hiring']" routerLinkActive="active">Hiring Managers</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown_menu"><a class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" [routerLink]="['/partners']" routerLinkActive="active" aria-expanded="true" data-toggle="dropdown">Partners</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                            <div class="menu_item">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{bitBucketUrl}}library/images/corporate/home/p-ico5.png">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['/partners/content-owners']" routerLinkActive="active" >Content Owner</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu_item">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{bitBucketUrl}}library/images/corporate/home/p-ico3.png">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['/partners/influencers']" routerLinkActive="active" >Influencers</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu_item">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{bitBucketUrl}}library/images/corporate/home/p-ico2.png">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['/partners/localmasters-for-startup']" routerLinkActive="active" >Localmasters for Startup</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu_item">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{bitBucketUrl}}library/images/corporate/home/p-ico4.png">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['/partners/customer-training-solutions']" routerLinkActive="active" >Customer Training Solutions</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="menu_item">
                                <img class="img-fluid" src="{{bitBucketUrl}}library/images/corporate/home/p-ico1.png">
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink]="['/partners/solution-partner-program']" routerLinkActive="active" >Solution Partner Program</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-template #individual_page>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/individual/signup']" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/individual/how_it_works']" routerLinkActive="active">How It Works</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/individual/personal_coaching']" routerLinkActive="active">Be a Mentor</a></li>
                  </ng-template>
                </ul> 
                <button class="btn top-btn" [routerLink]="['/login']" type="button">Sign In</button>
                <!-- (click)="showSiteMap = !showSiteMap" -->
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </header>
```

The above code works as expeceted but leave a error as shown in screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I believe that `getElementsByClassName` returns the collection, so you have to specify which element of that collection you're trying to access.

Comment: use document.querySelector(`.homemenu`)

Comment: Still same issue. I updated to querySelector with `.homemenu`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` returns [`HTMLCollection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection).

You have to specify the exact item within the `HTMLCollection`, that you want to use `scrollTo` on. Ex.:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('homemenu')[0].scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Or use more modern function to query html, like `querySelector`. Ex.:

```js
document.querySelector('.homemenu').scrollTo(0, 0);
```

##### To updated question

As I can see, you have that class assigned to element, that is rendered by angular. Make sure to call this function only when angular has rendered this tag.

Also, if code works as expected, then you can just check for null value the element, to get rid of the error:

```js
document.querySelector('.homemenu')?.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Comment: Unfurtunately this is not helping. i am getting same error.

Comment: @Santosh check updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

`document.querySelector('.homemenu').scrollTo({top : 0});`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did updated my code according to it. But not working. getting same error.

Comment: I will execute and check your code